# Multiple wifi connections through one modem

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I would like to set up a wifi network for my own private use, separate from my family's home wifi. Getting a second set up from the cable company is not an option. From what I have found online, it is possible to connect one router to another to boost the signal or for other networking purposes. My question is this: Will connecting a new router to my existing one give me another network to work with? If so, what would the impact be on the original network be (will it be slower)?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to your question is "Yes", this will work - sort of.

The effect will be that you have a network within a network.  You will be able to reach your families network, but (because of NAT on the router), they won't be able to reach your network.    It also means you will have "double nat" - any requests you make to the outside world will appear to come from the families IP address, and some things may not work because of this (VOIP and things which require pinholing / port mapping in the routers).   It is generally practical though.

As you will be sharing your family network, when you are using the Internet it will be coming off the available speed and any limits they have.

You also need to configure the WIFI aspect of it.  You will want to ensure your Wireless is using a different channel (at least 3 higher or lower) then the family network to prevent contention of that network.

You need to ensure that your router is set up with a different IP range to your families - I'd suggest setting the LAN range to 172.16.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 as it is unlikely that their router is using this, but that range is part of a range set aside for internal (NAT) use.